# Running Query on Conditional Probability graph

Tags: probability

I want to run the following query. P(Rain | WetGrass = True).
[image]

What I know:

1. Because we are given the child, Rain and Sprinkler are no longer conditionally independent.
2. My first approach is to use Bayes rule --> $$ P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B) $$
   But given the truth tables and the formula, I am having trouble proceeding. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way to go.   You just have to keep applying the law of total probability and definition of conditional independence until you have probabilities available in the table.

For instance: you don't have the joint probability for $W,R$ but you do have the conditional probabilities for $W$ when given $R,S$ and when given $R,S^\complement$.   So use the law of total probability.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R\mid W) =&~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(W, R)}{\mathsf P(R)} \\[1ex]  =&~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(W,R,S)+\mathsf P(W,R,S^\complement)}{\mathsf P(R)} \\[1ex] =&~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(R,S)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R,S^\complement)}{\mathsf P(R)} \end{align}$$

Have you got it?   Can you see what to do next?

Now, again you don't have the joint probability for $R,S$ but you do have the conditional probabilities for each when given $C$ or when given $C^\complement$.   Further they are conditionally independent when given each.   So, again, apply LoTP, and then you can use the definition of conditional independence.

You can tidy the result up a little, but it will still be a bit busy.   Still, however, you should have every factor available from the diagram.   Then just substitute and simplify.

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R\mid W) =&~ \dfrac{\left\{\substack{\large\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(R,S\mid C)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R,S^\complement\mid C)\big)\,\mathsf P(C)\\\large+\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(R,S\mid C^\complement)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R,S^\complement\mid C^\complement)\big)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)}\right\}}{\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)} \\[1ex] =&~ \dfrac{\left\{\substack{\large\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(S\mid C)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid C)\big)\,\mathsf P(C)\\\large+\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(S\mid C^\complement)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid C^\complement)\big)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)}\right\}}{\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)} \\[1ex] =&~ \dfrac{\left\{\substack{\large\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(S\mid C)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid C)\big)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(C)\\\large+\big(\mathsf P(W\mid R,S)\,\mathsf P(S\mid C^\complement)+\mathsf P(W\mid R,S^\complement)\,\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid C^\complement)\big)\,\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)}\right\}}{\mathsf P(R\mid C)\,\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(R\mid C^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C^\complement)}\end{align}$$

Comment: I am puzzled as to how the probability that the sprinkler is on is 0.10 and the probability that the sprinkler is off is 0.50.   Don't those probabilities have to add to 1.0?

Comment: (+1)I had the same doubt. And the same also happens with the truth table for WetGrass. Why so?

Comment: @user247327 No, $0.1$ is the probability the sprinkler is on when it *is* cloudy; $\mathsf P(S\mid C)=0.1$. Where as $0.5$ is the probability that the sprinkler is *on* when it is *not* cloudy; $\mathsf P(S\mid C^\complement)=0.5$.  Notice that the first column is whether $C$ is true or not.

Comment: @Christian Likewise the bottom table are the probabilities that the grass is wet when given the four states of Sprinkler and Raining.  $$\mathsf P(W\mid S,R)=0.99, \mathsf P(W\mid S,R^\complement)=0.90, \mathsf P(W\mid S^\complement, R)=0.90, \mathsf P(W\mid S^\complement, R^\complement)=0.00$$

Answer (score 0):

"No, 0.1is the probability the sprinkler is on when it is cloudy; P(S∣C)=0.1
P(S∣C)=0.1. Where as 0.5 is the probability that the sprinkler is on when it is not cloudy."

That's not what your chart says. It has "t: P(s)= 0.10, P(t)= 0.60" both under "Cloudy".